# How to append data frame in a for loop and concatenate as one data frame in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, append

I am new to R and trying to run a for loop which produces a dataframe for each run I would like to store each data frame into the list and later concatenate it as one data frame in R. I am trying to achieve like below but it throws error. What is the best way to append data frame into a list in for loop and concatenate list of data frames as one?

```
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(osrm)
df<- read.csv('csv path')
liist<-list()
for(i in df$h3_longitude) {
  for (j in df$h3_latitude){
    iso <- osrmIsochrone(loc = c(i, j), breaks = seq(0,90,30),osrm.profile='car')
    liist[[iso]]<- iso
    bind_rows(liist)
}
       }
```

error:-

```
Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, iso, value = iso) : 
  invalid subscript type 'list'
Error in `[[<-`(`*tmp*`, iso, value = iso): invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Comment: I guess your `liist` is not named.  Perhaps you want `liist[[i]][[j]] <- iso` after looping over the sequence of the vector instead of the values

Comment: It's generally better to keep the data in a list by itself until after the `for` loops before trying to combine into a single frame. For instance, `liist <- list(); for (i in ...) for (j in ...) { ...; liist <- c(liist, list(osm)); }; }`, and then once the loops are done, then `alldata <- bind_rows(liist)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `liist[[iso]]<- iso`.
`iso` as the output of `osrmIsochrone()` is a dataframe.
You use this dataframe as an index to `liist` - that can't go well.

The for-loops

```
for(i in df$h3_longitude) {
  for (j in df$h3_latitude){
  }
}
```

show that you want all combinations of `i` and `j` from the longitude and latitude columns of `df`.

But what you want is a flat list.

In R, you do this better with `expand.grid(vec1, vec2)`.

```
library(osrm)
df<- read.csv('csv path')
pairings <- expand.grid(df$h3_longitude, df$h3_latitude)
dfs <- lapply(data.frame(t(pairings)), function(v) {
  osrmIsochrone(loc=c(v[1], v[2]),
                breaks=seq(0,90,30),
                osrm.profile='car')
})
res_df <- Reduce(rbind, dfs)
```

With a for-loop it would look like this:

```
library(osrm)
df<- read.csv('csv path')
pairings <- expand.grid(df$h3_longitude, df$h3_latitude)
dfs <- list()
for (i in 1:nrow(pairings)) {
  v <- pairings[i,]
  dfs[[i]] <- osrmIsochrone(loc=c(v[1], v[2]),
                            breaks=seq(0,90,30),
                            osrm.profile='car')
}
res_df <- Reduce(rbind, dfs)
```

Comment: `Reduce(rbind, dfs)` is no better than `dfs <- rbind(dfs, newdf)`, which still works but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). for each row added, it makes a complete copy of all rows in `old`, which works but starts to slow down a lot. It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for pointing that out! Sure, then one should do `do.call(rbind, dfs)`!